# Django pagination and current page with other value currency name button "USD" or "EUR"

Tags: python, html, django, pagination, href

I try to pass 2 values in my Django crypto currency project page_number and currency for example USD.

1. Page Load Crypto currencies with defalut converter to price in USD
2. User have possibility to change currency from USD to EUR or JPY or CNY
3. When Im on 1 page it works fine but on second and further takes me back to the first page convert only crypto currencies belonging that page

My question is how to convert crypto to USD to EUR or JPY or CNY like on first page
that the page I am currently on would be sent(saved)

index_buttons.py

```
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-md mb-4">
    {% for item in buttons %}
            
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}?currency_type={{item.currency_type}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark {{item.active}}" role="button">{{item.display_text}}</a>
    
    {% endfor %} 
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    
    selected_currency_type = request.GET.get('currency_type', "USD")
    
    buttons = [
            {"currency_type": "USD", "active": "", "display_text": "USD"},
            {"currency_type": "EUR", "active": "", "display_text": "Euro"},
            {"currency_type": "CNY", "active": "", "display_text": "Chinese Yuan"},
            {"currency_type": "JPY", "active": "", "display_text": "Japanese Yen"},
        ]
    for button in buttons:
        if button['currency_type'] == selected_currency_type:
            button['active'] = 'active'

    currecies_list = load_currencies(selected_currency_type)
    
    paginator = Paginator(currecies_list, 12)
    page_number = request.GET.get("page")
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
                "user": request.user,
                "page_obj": page_obj,
                "buttons" : buttons,
                "active_currency_name" : selected_currency_type,
                    }
    return render(request, "web/index.html", context)
```

I also tried change href in buttoms but it doesn't do anything

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}?page={{ page_obj.number }}/currency_type={{item.currency_type}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark {{item.active}}" role="button">{{item.display_text}}</a>
```

Any ideas or hints how to change how to change the cryptocurrency to currency converter on each page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [Django session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/). This will save the value in the `request` you are passing on. An implementation might look like this:

```
def index(request):
     
    selected_currency_type = request.GET.get('currency_type')

    if not selected_currency_type:
        selected_currency_type = request.session['currency_type']
    else:
        request.session['currency_type'] = selected_currency_type

    buttons = #and the rest of your code from that point on
```

So the code gets the new `currency_type` and if it does not exist, it gets the last value from the session variables. If it did find one in the GET-request it sets the session variable equal to the newly chosen value so the next time the code can use that value.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change anything when im on http://127.0.0.1:8000/?currency_type=EUR and I will go to the second page http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2 and I click again the currency EURO django return first page with http://127.0.0.1:8000/?currency_type=EUR I think I need to pass {{ page_obj.number }}  some where

Comment: Try changing the `/` to a `&` in your href in your template: `?page={{ page_obj.number }}&currency_type={{item.currency_type}}`